# To be or not to be: window.onload

Tags: javascript

Silly question but when I write `window.onload = alert('hi')` I get the alert.

However if I test for its existence: `if (window.onload) alert("exists")` I get `undefined`. How come?

Comment: see if my answer fits your needs.

Answer (score 7):

You are calling the `alert` method (which executes immediately) and assigning its return value (`undefined`) to `onload`.

If you want to assign a function to `onload` then you need to assign an actual function, and not the return value of any old function call.

For example:

```
onload = function () { 
    alert('hi');
};
```

or

```
function createHiAlertFunction() {
    return function () {
        alert('hi');
    }
}
onload = createHiAlertFunction();
```

Generally speaking, however, you should avoid assigning things to the event handler properties and use event binding methods instead. That way you aren't having to juggle things if you want multiple functions to be called.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    alert('hi');
});​​​
```

Note that this isn't supported by old-ish IE, so you probably want to use one of the many libraries (such as YUI or jQuery) that provide an abstraction layer that includes support for the old, proprietary Microsoft way.

Comment: I don't understand why I am assigning it... I am not using the assignment operator `=`, I thought `if (window.onload)` would just be a condition and whatever is after gets executed if condition returns true..

Comment: You **are** using the assignment operator. Look again: `window.onload = alert('hi')`

Comment: `if (window.onload)` is a condition. It mean "If something with a true value has been assigned to the `onload` property". It doesn't mean "If the document has loaded". The property holds a function that will be executed when the document has loaded.

Comment: Sorry I think there is a misunderstanding - the two lines are separate, not one block of code. If you just do `if (window.onload) alert("exists")` it still returns undefined

Comment: If you assign nothing to the event handler property, then it won't have a true value. As I said, it is a place where an event handler function can live, not a boolean that tells you if the document has loaded or not.

Comment: I guess I'm just used to thinking of this form as `if (something here exists, thus true)`

Comment: Focus on the name. *on* load ("It is true that something will happen when the document loads") vs. *has* loaded (which doesn't exist, unless you write an onload event handler to set it).

Comment: @Quentin I guess he wants to test if the onload handler exists (as you would test for a certain property), not if the document has loaded yet.

Comment: @user1019031 — Why do you expect it to be a true value if you don't assign a function to it?

Answer (score 1):

`window.onload` fires an event. By default it has no value, its value is set by the user when something is needed to happen when everything is ready. If you didn't set a value, it will be `undefined`

Comment: `onload` doesn't fire an event. It holds a function that is called when a particular event (the document finishing loading) fires.

Comment: Yeah, it fires the function assosiated with it, in this case it holds the `alert` function result, which is `underfined`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
if(typeof window.onload !== "undefined") alert("exists!")
```

This checks explicitly if there is an onload property on the `window` object.

edit:

The `undefined` you see is the return value of the alert function.

Comment: @Quentin Why don't you get it? He does not want to check if the document has loaded. He wants to test if `onload` is present as property of `window`. The Check with typeof returns either Object or Function if it is.

Comment: If a function is assigned to it, then it will have a true value, so what difference would using typeof make?

Answer (score -1):

Where do you fire that script? if window.onload returns false it means that the page has not been completly loaded.

Comment: OK interesting, so does `window.onload` get "cleared" after the page has loaded and thus only exists during page parsing?

Comment: No. If `window.onload` returns false, it means that either nothing or something that is false has been assigned to it. It is a place where event handlers live, not a boolean that tells you if the document has finished loading.